# How to create an instance of IEnumerable<MyClass> in Silverlight Client?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Looks like ArrayList is not available for SL sandbox.  so I can't do something like 
var myCollection= new ArrayList();

So how to creata an instance of IEnumerable , then I can add many instances to the collection in SL client? Or what kind of collection I should use at Silverlight client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) in MSDN.

`ArrayList` isn't strongly typed, avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) which implements [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)? There are very few (if any) cases where you'd want to use an ArrayList in preference to a generic List. It's really a legacy from the pre-generics era.

Answer (score 0):

Other things that implement IEnumerable are System.Collections.Generic.List, any array (string[], int[]), also you probably do have the ArrayList, you're just not properly qualifying it with the namespace.